# I can't edit file "httpd-xampp.conf" to enable access XAMPP

Tags: macos, terminal, configuration, xampp, editor

I have a problem to edit file "httpd-xampp.conf"
when I typed nano httpd-xampp.conf?

***can not open editor***
[image: can not open editor]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use alternative ways: `vi httpd-xampp.conf` & `vim httpd-xampp.conf`
Here's [a link](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialAdvanced_vi.html)! some info

or you can install `nano`, do: `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` and after `apt-get install nano`. You can run with `sudo` in front if you are not `root`.

or check the permission for `httpd-xampp.conf`, in the main folder where is the file located do: `ls -ll` and see if looks good...

Hope, helps)

Comment: I used it, I can't access.